# How to build face filters using MLKit

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, face-detection, google-mlkit

I would like to implement live face filters like those seen in Snapchap. Examples including face retouch, virtual lipstick, nose shrinking, etc. What is the best way to develop them in Android? Can we use available SDKs like Google ML Kit using their face functions, or better to use specialized GANs?

Comment: mediapipe can help to get landmarks of face easily. since it is compatible with android. after landmark detection you should make a copy paste properyly

Comment: Tnx. Yes we can "get" the landmarks part, but now that we want to change them, how to "set" it back so to transform the face part?

Comment: since the landmark points will generate a polygon, you may fill this polygon with some morphological operations(opencv fillPolly, remap etc. may help). directly copying the shape to target landmark will not appear fine i believe. but some face application is directly putting shape to the center of nose also. but good transformation would be better

Comment: If nose got smaller, copying back doesn't help because of residu of previous nose is still there